# AAPT: error: unexpected element <activity> found in <manifest><application><activity>

Tags: java, android, android-studio

It specifies

```
ERROR:C:\Users\rafaw\OneDrive\Desktop\pp_rafa\pp_rafa\remindertest\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:27: AAPT: error: unexpected element <activity> found in  <manifest><application><activity>.
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.remindertest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="31" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:testOnly="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ReminderTest" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.remindertest.Activity2"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.remindertest.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true" >
            <activity android:name="com.example.remindertest.DestinationActivity" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.example.remindertest.AlarmReceiver" />

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.remindertest.androidx-startup"
            android:exported="false" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.emoji2.text.EmojiCompatInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup" />
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I can launch my app/emulator though but a few features does not work. Do you guys know what's happening? Also when I open AndroidManifest it's normal but when I launch emulator it turns red, if I exit and open again it's back to normal yellow, though there is a red underline under the destination activity problem

Comment: "unexpected element <activity> found".  
<activity android:name="com.example.remindertest.DestinationActivity" /> 
Move this out of the MainActivity <activity> </activity>.

Comment: so I moved it outside MainActivity but when I reload the app it moves back to inside mainactivity

Comment: You probably moved it from \debug\AndroidManifest.xml. The manifest you posted here is from app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Try defining these attributes in your build.gradle(app-level).  android:versionCode="1, android:versionName="1.0". android:minSdkVersion="21",  android:targetSdkVersion="31" and make your manifest cleaner. 
Then take out this line <activity android:name="com.example.remindertest.DestinationActivity" /> 
from inside your launcher activity

Answer (score 0):

update this manifest file with your manifest, and rebuild.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.remindertest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="31" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:testOnly="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ReminderTest" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.remindertest.Activity2"
            android:exported="false" />


            <activity android:name="com.example.remindertest.DestinationActivity" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.remindertest.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.example.remindertest.AlarmReceiver" />

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.remindertest.androidx-startup"
            android:exported="false" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.emoji2.text.EmojiCompatInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup" />
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```